# Unable to create local variable inside coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin coroutines topic and there is one issue, which totally blocks me from using them. I have the following code to run with coroutines:

```
runBlocking {
    for (i in 0 until args[1].toInt()) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            OuterObject().run()
    }
}
```

And my OuterObject class has the following code in run() method:

```
override fun run() {
    ...
    logger.info(){ "Checkpoint 0" }
    var innerObject: InnerObject = InnerObject(some_parameter = 1)
    logger.info(){ "Checkpoint 1" }
    ...
}
```

All the coroutines got started from the loop but reach only "Checkpoint 0". There are no log messages or any other actions after innerObject creation attempt.

The first thing I tried is to create another object, but it seems like the issue is general and does not depend on object's class. I've tried with DateTime(), Gson() and some others - each time coroutines stop at this point. I've also tried to add exception handled to the coroutine but there is no exception catched - the coroutine just silently stops.

What is the reason behind this and how can I avoid it?

Version of kotlinx-coroutines-core: 1.2.2

UPDATE 1:

I've checked a primitive type assignment and it works. Both "Checkpoint 0" and "Checkpoint 1" appear in console logs. The issue is only with complex types.

```
override fun run() {
    ...
    logger.info(){ "Checkpoint 0" }
    var test = 1
    logger.info(){ "Checkpoint 1" }
    ...
}
```

UPDATE 2:

@gladed and @Sam, you are right. The article of @roman-elizarov also helped me out: [The reason to avoid GlobalScope](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc). It was wrong to call "launch" from GlobalScope - it is not related to the runBlocking scope.

I've modified my code in the following way:

```
runBlocking {(0 until args[1].toInt()).forEach {
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        OuterObject().run()
    }
}
```

I got some further issues with running the code this way but they were due to not optimal concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`launch()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) starts a new coroutine. But you're not waiting for it to complete. Instead, consider:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    (0 until args[1].toInt()).forEach {
        launch {
            OuterObject().run()
        }
    }
}
```

This way, `runBlocking` won't return until all the launched jobs are complete. (Credit to @Sam on removing GlobalScope.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I’ve tried your recommendation but unfortunately the result is the same. As I understand, joinAll is not required in general. runBlocking launches new coroutines in own scope and it will automatically wait for all the launched jobs to finish.

Comment: @Agita `runBlocking` will wait for jobs launched in its own scope, but you're launching your job in the unrelated `GlobalScope`. You can replace `GlobalScope.launch` with just `launch`.

Comment: We might need to see what is going on in Inner/OuterObject to help more.

Comment: @Sam, indeed, this was the reason. I've achieved the result with removal of GlobalScope and specifying Dispatchers.Default for "launch" (see the final code update in the post).

Guys, thank you very much for your help.